# Banach and Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorems -- are they related?

Tags: posets, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fixed-point-theorems

It there any known way of obtaining the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem) from the [Tarski fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster-Tarski_theorem) or vice-versa?

Comment: I'm intrigued - have you any indication that they might be?

Comment: I was thinking that the metric (in the Banach version) induces a foliation of the space, which could be seen as a poset.  If things 'line up' just right, contraction could preserve this foliation just right, so that the Tarski LFP exists and is the same as the Banach one.

Comment: Okay, you've sold me.  I'll follow this question ...

Comment: @Michal: you should make that an answer.  It isn't exactly right, but close enough.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hello,

I just found the question, so the answer might come a bit too lat, but..
Have a look at:

*Paweł Waszkiewicz, "Common patterns for metric and ordered fixed point theorems.",
In Proceedings of the 7th Workshop on Fixed Points in Computer Science (Luigi Santocanale ed.), 2010, pp. 83-87.*

I attended this talk last summer, and it addresses exactly your question.

Comment: Here is a link: http://tcs.uj.edu.pl/~pqw/waszkificsfinal.pdf

Comment: Perfect!  And my intuition was not too far off either, which is nice!

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Jacques, I turn my comment into an answer.

This is not exactly what you ask for, but it is related. Efe Ok in Section 3.4 in Chapter 6 of his yet-to-be-written book on ordered sets gives a proof of the Banach fixed point theorem using the Kantorovitch-Tarski fixed point theorem: <s>[files.nyu.edu/eo1/public/Book-PDF/CHAPTER%205.pdf](http://files.nyu.edu/eo1/public/Book-PDF/CHAPTER%25205.pdf)</s> https://sites.google.com/a/nyu.edu/efeok/books/CHAPTER%205.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Look the article : 
M.Jawahiri, D. Misane, M. Pouzet. Retracts: graphs and ordrerd sets from the metric point of view.
Contemporary Mathematics, 1986, vol. 57 pp. 175-226